# C Pipe to STDIN of another program and execl

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I don't understand why the program in the execl-command doesn't get the input from the parent process:

My code: (I removed error-handling and some other steps to make it simpler)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     int pipefd[2];
     pipe(pipefd);
     pid_t pid = fork();
     switch(pid){
         case -1:
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         case 0:
             close(pipefd[1]);
             dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
             close(pipefd[0]);
             execl("/usr/bin/wc", "-w", NULL);
             fflush(stdout);
             exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
         default:
             close(pipefd[0]);
             FILE *pipewrite = fdopen(pipefd[1], "w");
             char *ar[] = {"W1", "W2", "W3", "W4", "W5"};
             for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                 fputs(ar[i], pipewrite);
                 fflush(pipewrite);
             }
             fflush(pipewrite);
             fclose(pipewrite);
     }
     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

If I start the program, the output should be 5.

Answer (score 1):

The `execl` call is problematic.

This

```
execl("/usr/bin/wc", "-w", NULL);
```

needs to be:

```
execl("/usr/bin/wc", "wc", "-w", NULL);
```

i.e., you need to pass the command (`wc`) as an argument  to `execl` as well.

The next problem you'll see is that `wc` doesn't 5. it's because all the stdin stuff you pass from parent process are seen as single word (due to lack of whitespaces).
Basically, if you do:

```
   fputs(ar[i], stdout);
```

in the parent process, what see on stdout is what'll be seen by the child process.

Add a whitespace in some way. For example, you could call `fputs` again:

```
   fputs(ar[i], pipewrite);
   fputs(" ", pipewrite);
```

Alternatively, you can have spaces in the strings:

```
char *ar[] = {"W1 ", "W2 ", "W3 ", "W4 ", "W5"};
```

Comment: Also `fprintf(pipewrite, "%s\n", ar[i]);` could be used.

Comment: Good idea. Saves an extra call to `fputs`.

Comment: Ok thanks, that works. But if I run the program in the shell, 5 is set as an input for the next command.

user@pc:~$ ./dsort
user@pc:~$ 5

And after the five there is the blank?

Comment: That's probably you are not reaping the child process. i.e. `wait(NULL);` call before `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);` at the end main.